# unexpected code execution order in shell script start and stop functions

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the below script,

```
#!/bin/bash
#test1.sh

echo "test ... "
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 
do
   #echo "Welcome $i times"
done
exit 0
```

and the output is

```
test ... 
./test11.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./test11.sh: line 7: `done'
```

Note that it prints, `test...` first, then complains about syntax error.

However in the below script

```
#test2.sh
 #!/bin/bash 


    case "$1" in
        'start')
                echo "in start 1"
                echo "in start 2"
                echo "in start 3"
                echo "test ... "
                for i in 1 2 3 4 5 
                do
                  #echo "Welcome $i times"
                done
                ;;
        'stop')
                echo "in stop"
                ;;
        'restart')
                stop ; echo "Sleeping..."; sleep 1 ; 
                echo "in restart"
                ;;
        'status')
                echo "in status"
                ;;
        *)  
                echo
                echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop | restart | status }"
                echo
                exit 1
                ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```

The output is

```
./test10.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./test10.sh: line 18: `            done'
```

Script complains about syntax error at `line:18`. Since it's a scripting language, it should be done by line by line executions. In the above code, the execution should first go to `start`, then continue line by line execution.  So I would expect the output messages should be printed first [`echo "in start 1" etc`], then the syntax error.

Why the above two shell scripts behave differently ? Is shell scripts are parsed for errors first before begining execution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop in the second example is embedded in a `case` statement, rather than being a top-level statement. The entire `case` statement needs to be parsed in order to execute it, and that means parsing the `for` loop in the `start` clause, even if `$1` (when expanded) doesn't result in the `start` being selected.

A syntax error is, by definition, the result of something that can't be *parsed*, not something that can't be *evaluated*.